# A Problem Of Convergence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, means

I am newly learning about the convergence of sequences and I want to share a problem which I am unable to make through. The problem is as follows:-

Find a closed form for the limit
$$f(m)=\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\prod_{i=1}^n \frac{m+i}{n}\right)^{1/n}$$

I have learned a theorem in my book where it was written that if there is a sequence whose terms are all positive and the sequence converges to a finite limit then the Geometric mean of $n$ terms of that sequence will approach the same limit as that of the sequence itself, provided $n$ approaches infinity.
I thought of using the above result somehow to figure out the answer of my question.

Though it is not provided here I assumed $m$ as a positive real number to increase the simplicity and to make use of the theorem.
Is the result which I am thinking to make use of (unable to make use of though) will help to solve the problem? If yes then please provide me with a hint else help me with a solution of the problem

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to type the expression.  I'm not sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: Are you trying to find a closed form the function $f(m)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\prod_{i=1}^n\frac{m+i}{n}\right)^{1/n}$?

Comment: @R.Burton yes I am trying to figure out that only.

Comment: Can you prove that $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } \frac{{(n + m)!}}{{n!n^m }} = 1$ and $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } \frac{1}{n}\sqrt[n]{{n!}} = \frac{1}{e}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These kinds of limits can be reduced nicely with the root-to-ratio limit:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{a_n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$$

In your case this becomes:

\begin{align}L&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{m+n+1}{n+1}\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{m+k}{n+1}\frac n{m+k}\\&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\prod_{k=1}^n\frac n{n+1}\\&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac n{n+1}\right)^n\\&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[\left(1-\frac1{n+1}\right)^{n+1}\right]^{n/(n+1)}\\&=e^{-1}\end{align}

Comment: (+1) I'm surprised I've never seen this approach before

Comment: @Simply Beautiful Art I want to know about the root-to-ratio limit property which has been used in solving the problem, does this property require all the terms of a sequence to be positive in order to apply?

Comment: @It'sprobable: yes one needs all terms to be positive and this is equivalent to your hint. See my answer. The root to ratio is one of my favorite tools but since it was already used here I resorted to your hint. All these theorems are consequences of a more general result called Cesaro-Stolz Theorem.

Answer (score 3):

Your hint is the way to go here. Let's do it that way. Your hint can be stated as

> **Lemma 1**: Let $\{a_n\} $ be a sequence of positive terms such that $a_n\to L$ as $n\to\infty $. Then $$\sqrt[n] {a_1a_2\dots a_n} \to L$$ as $n\to \infty $.

The key here is to choose $a_n$ properly. Let us choose $$a_n=\left. \prod_{i=1}^{n+1}\frac{m+i}{n+1}\middle/\prod_{i=1}^{n}\frac{m+i}{n}\right.$$ so that $$a_n=\frac{m+n+1}{n+1}\cdot\frac{n^n}{(n+1)^n}$$ so that $a_n\to 1/e$.

Next note that $$a_1a_2\dots a_n=\frac{1}{m+1}\prod_{i=1}^{n+1}\frac{m+i} {n+1}$$ and by Lemma 1 the $n$-th root of above expression tends to $1/e$. Since $\sqrt [n] {m+1}\to 1$ it follows that $$\left(\prod_{i=1}^{n+1}\frac{m+i}{n+1}\right) ^{1/n}\to \frac{1}{e}$$ Raising the expression on left to power $n/(n+1)$ we can see that the above equation holds if the exponent $1/n$ is replaced with $1/(n+1)$. And then we can replace $n$ by $n-1$ everywhere to see that the desired limit is $1/e$.

---

You should be able to show that lemma 1 above is equivalent to the root-to-ratio limit result used in another answer here.